# Clicking a button in a parsed page by php

Tags: php, forms, button

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

I would like to push the button appearing at:
http://www.miafoto.it/iPhone/inarrivo/php/atacError.php?partenza=Piazza+Bologna&arrivo=Via+Edoardo+D%27Onofrio&language=en&userLatitude=41.913325&userLongitude=12.521108
directly in the script doing the parsing of an external web site. How may I do it?
That script presently returns the full html returned by the site.

Comment: Also check out http://www.googleguide.com/category/query-input/ for other issues that may arise. (In particular if your case is urgent to you.)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by installing a proxy on the remote server and unlocking the website from there. I think I threaded ten pathways before getting to there. Also the automatic click was not possible as the page had a catcha test soon behind.